# How to Upgrade Joomla! 1.0.15 Stable to Joomla! 3.1

Tags: joomla, upgrade

Can any one explain me how to upgrade joomla step by step..

I want to Upgrade Joomla! 1.0.15 Stable to Joomla! 3.1  with the latest version

Thank's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will first have to upgrade to Joomla 1.5. To do this, read the [tutorial provided on the Joomla Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5%3aMigrating_from_1.0.x_to_1.5_Stable)

[Joomla 1.0 to 1.5 migrator](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=430&t=388744&p=2990436&hilit=Migrator+for+joomla+1.0.15#p2990436)

Once done, download and install [JUpgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/11658) which is a component that will upgrade your Joomla 1.5 site to 2.5

Once you have Joomla 2.5 up and running, enter the admin panel and go to the component "**Joomla Update**" and select the global "options" icon (top right in your screen). Change the settings from **Long Term Release (LTS)** to **STS** and save. Now go back to Joomla update and you will see that the 3.x version is available! Click UPDATE and within seconds your site will be on Joomla 3

Please do bare in mind that this process will not upgrade your Joomla 1.0 3rd party extensions therefore you will need to install the J3 versions or simply find alternatives.

Please also consider that it might be quicker and easier to actually create your website again and start from scratch with Joomla 3.1.5

Hope this helps

Comment: This will work - however I imagine there will be a LOT of things that will break.  You should know that going into it.  Migrating to 1.5 was painful for some people, but the jump to 3.0 was even more painful (in my opinion).  Depending how your site is build/coded - there will be issues.  This is not an easy upgrade, good luck.

Comment: SP Upgrade can migrate directly from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 3.x and may save some time. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/15609

Comment: @NeilRobertson - Good point, however I would say that upgrading from J2.5 to 3.x is a simply 1 click update and saves you 35 euros ;)