# Migrating just article content of Joomla 1.0 to 2.5.x / 3.x?

Tags: php, security, joomla, migration

I have a simple website using Joomla 1.0.15, just having articles in some categories. As I want to install or remove components from admin area, I got: "You are not authorised to view this resource" or something like that. This is uncommon, this site is about 5 years old, and never got error message like that.

I think my website is hacked ??
I have set safe_mode = off in php.ini, turn of sh404sef, removing .htaccess file etc ... and it still does not work.

Then i try to upgrade to Joomla 2.5.x / 3.x . I found that i must migrate to Joomla 1.5.x first, then from there to 2.5.x.
I got problem installing "migration.zip" component in my Joomla 1.0.x (always alert/err message pop up is shown).

Is there another way to migrate the website ? May be just get the article section, category, article id and the content of Joomla 1.0.x , then import it to Joomla 2.5.x / 3.x ?

I don't need components, modules, mambots (if any) of the old site. How to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115355/how-to-upgrade-joomla-1-0-15-stable-to-joomla-3-1/19115662#19115662

Answer (score 0):

You could definetely go for the manual export/import via some sql if you only care about articles and categories, or for a more "clean" way of doing make a copy of the whole website on your local dev. env. and debug it, make the migration localy and there you go ...

Answer (score 0):

Agree with kriss2 that if all you care about is articles, it's pretty easy to do the sql to change the fields and just put the articles in the uncategorised category that is part of 1.6+.  Leave **asset_id blank (not 0)** You will then need to create assets.  You can run a cli for that but also in the user interface copy all articles to a new category.